# Music Cowboy bebop

Tags: cowboy-bebop

I have a question about a song in one episode of cowboy bebop.
This episode is the number 10 about Jets story.
I would like to know the name of the one which starts approximately at 5:30 when jet is searching his bar’s exgirl.
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song name is 'The Singing Sea'.

Comment: Welcome to A&M, could you expend a bit upon your answer. For example by including the artist, or if it's part of a OST, which OST cd is part of.